# Freshdesk API : types of a ticket

Tags: php, api, integration, freshdesk

I have a problem. How can I get available types of tickets

[image]

and type of certain ticket to make field to update type through API ?

When I get info about a ticket I get this just as plain text

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are making a GET request to view the details of a ticket. That will display the type which the ticket belongs to.

You need to make a GET request to list all the ticket fields. [Refer](https://developers.freshdesk.com/api/#list_all_ticket_fields).

Then if you want to create a ticket with a specific type, mention one of the values you got from the above GET request for ticket fields and create a ticket.

This should help!